# Bittrex invalid api key error in python

Tags: python, api

Please help me if you can.
I am using python 2.7 with the bittrex wrapper. I requested and received the bittrex api key and secret key as well.

If I use the bittrex.ticker() command, I get all the results, however when I want to get my balances I get an invalid api key error.

I am 100% sure that my API keys are right. I checked them several times, even requested a new API key and i got the same error. So there must be something else.

If you can or have any idea what could be wrong, please help.

Below is my code:

```
from bittrex import Bittrex

APIKEY = "XXXXXXXXX"

SECRETKEY = "XXXXXXXXX"

bittrex = Bittrex(APIKEY, SECRETKEY)


print bittrex.get_balances()
```

The error message i am getting :

```
{u'message': u'APIKEY_INVALID', u'result': None, u'success': False}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Change to `bittrex = Bittrex(APIKEY, SECRETKEY)`, without enclosed in `""`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually it is the api key itself. Edited the original post because it was misleading. Still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This happens from time to time on TREX they got a bug on their backend i believe, please report to their support.

I have done and i'm waiting on their side.

On my case the key works and then after sometimes it says it's invalid but then it says its valid again. Pretty annoying